# Which figure is the odd one out?

Tags: puzzle

I'm not sure if I should ask this question here, and under which tag so feel free to re-tag or redirect me to another site.

**Anyway, which figure is the odd one out?**

[image]

Comment: A typical question where more than one answer could be correct, depending on which hemisphere this question is asked...

Comment: Seems very subjective.  My first thought was the first, as it is the only one in which like squares are next to each other.  It's also the only one in which all the squares are in a single connected block. I'm sure there are other, equally sensible, guesses.

Comment: I could make an argument for any one of the five options being "the" odd one out.

Comment: B is the only figure without an axis of symmetry,

Comment: Have you heard of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @awkward C and D have no axis of symmetry either, considering the colors of the squares.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right, I took too-hasty a look at the figures.

Answer (score 3):

The real challenge in this kind of puzzle is to find a reason for selecting any one of the five as odd one out.

Here's a start. I'll mark this community wiki - feel free to contribute.

$A$ is the only one ...

- with three white squares.
- with a white square in the North-East position.
- with all squares on consecutive radii

$B$ is the only one ...

- with a sequence of four radii that do not terminate in a square of some kind.

$C$ is the only one ...

- without a black square on the horizontal line.
- without a white square in the top position.
- with a black square in the North-East position.
- with a white square in the bottom position.

$D$ is the only one ...

- with black squares separating the white squares and whites separating the blacks.
- with a black square in the bottom position.
- with a black square in the North-West position.
- with different-colored squares on opposing radii (white on top, black on bottom)

$E$ is the only one ...

- with just one white square.
- without a square on the "/" diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

IMO **C** is the odd one.

What I have found, in every pattern if I consider the 2 black boxes then I can find the white box(es) within 180 degrees angular between the 2 black boxes and if I consider 2 white boxes I can find black box(es) within 180 degrees angular between the 2 white boxes.

In **C**, the location of the black box is such that it is not within the 180 degrees angular difference of the 2 white boxes.

Anyways the actual answer may differ but this is what I feel.